# Can't serve firebase functions

Tags: firebase, localhost, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#0) from Firebase Web Codelab, but I am facing a problem at step 5: after running the command `firebase serve`, I do not get the expected response 
`Listening at http://localhost:5000`, but instead I get:

`i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: ./
+  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000`

which is bad because functions are not being served, although `⚠  functions: Failed to emulate api` is not prompted, it remains "preparing to emulate functions" ad infinitum.

More information: `CLI Version: 3.18.4`
`Platform: win32`
`Node Version: v6.12.3` and I already tried going to ~/.config/configstore/ and deleting the @Google-Cloud folder in order to restart the whole process.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you are in the right track, the difference between the expected message (`Listening at http://localhost:5000`) and the message you get (`hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000`) is because you are using the new version of the CLI (v3.18.4) but the codelab chapter is not updated to reflect the new change in the logging message.

You can see the difference in the source-code [firebase-tools v2.2.1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/ab2d89a49267de2e38d00101173b738ed20c91b8/commands/serve.js#L26) where it displays

```
Listening at http://<HOST>:<PORT>
```

and in [firebase-tools v3.18.4](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/3d753bf730326908f9abf62d63200d6aa9edbf54/lib/serve/hosting.js#L41) it displays

```
hosting: Local server: http://<HOST>:<PORT>
```

And for the functions emulation, as you are in step5, you don't have yet functions, see [functions](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-web/blob/e0e97042504d537665dce122d0798c67d6247115/web-start/functions/index.js) in the codelab source code.